# ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package. I am genuinely stuck

Tags: python, importerror

Here is my **file structure:**
MainDir/
| Foo.py
| SubDir/
| |
| | Bar.py

**Foo.py:**

```
global var
var = 'value'
from SubDir import Bar
```

**Bar.py:**

```
from ..Foo import var
print(var)
```

With this code I am trying to get the value of var from Foo and get it in Bar.
I am getting this error while running Foo.py (and Bar.py): **ImportError
attempted relative import beyond top-level package**

I know that there are multiple questions like this but I did not succeed to fix it by looking at all of them. I am stuck on this problem for about a week. Thanks in advance!

Comment: None of your directories are considered to be a package. Also, it also depends on how you are running the script. Your modules/packages need to be in the python path. Also this seems to be issue of circular import here as well (two modules/packages importing each other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace: *from ..Foo import var* by *from Foo import var*

those .. are trying to go beyond top package

\MainDir>dir /b/s

\MainDir\Foo.py 
\MainDir\SubDir\Bar.py

[image]

Foo.py

```
global var
var = 'value'
from SubDir import Bar
```

Bar.py

```
from Foo import var
print(var)
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution it was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Have you created proper Python packages with `__init__.py`? Additionally, you are likely to run into circular import errors if you are importing the same files into each-other.

I suggest avoiding relative imports and use absolute imports instead.